# how to decide between DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateOperator vs Bashoperator to instantiate dataproc workflow template from composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I have a use case where I need to execute dataproc workflow template from composer. I am using set of gcloud commands to perform creation and instantiation of workflow template.
Now I want to implement it from composer so I got two options which can be used for implementation:
-use bashoperator to run the gcloud commands batch file
-Create the template and then use DataprocWorkflowTemplateInstantiateOperator for instantiation

I need know what approach is recommended and why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DataprocInstantiateInlineWorkflowTemplateOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5dbabddbacd0b2bde34034450de85a5e0dccc8fb/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.py#L1709) which create, instantiate and delete Workflow. More information about inline instantiate can be found in [GCP documentation.](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1beta2/projects.regions.workflowTemplates/instantiateInline)